# How to use Tasker to close an app when a different app gets closed

Tags: tasker, automation

I have a task setup that opens Co Pilot (satellite navigation) after I click on Dailyroads Voyager (blackbox recorder); this works really well. What I'd like to know is how to close Dailyroads Voyager once I exit Co Pilot by using Tasker.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

- Profile: Voyager Toggler
- Trigger: App: Voyager
- Task:

  - A1 : if ( %Count == 1 )
    A1a: Open Co-Pilot
    A1b: Set ( %Count = 0 )
    A1c: goto ( exit )
  - A2 : if  ( %Count == 0 )
    A2a: Home
    A2b: Kill Voayeger and Co-Pilot
    A2c: Set ( %Count = 1 )
    A2d: goto ( exit )

Now go to VARS in Tasker, create a new variable Count and set it to 1.

What's happening over here is that every second time app Voyager opens, it executes what you want.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new profile. The context has to be Application -> co pilot.
2. Leave the tasks empty. (You actually can't leave it empty but you can add some dummy task like: Alert -> Notify and add an If clause that will always fail. ie %asdasd12eqwe is set.
3. When finish with the dummy tasks go to the profile and click the task (where is the green arrow).
4. In the opened dialog click "Add exit task".
5. Here you should add the task to close dailyroads voyager: App -> Kill app -> dailyroads voyager.

This should do the trick. Although I must add that it is not really recommended to kill apps. I'm not really sure why.

Comment: When co pilot closes, it opens voyager, and then reopens copilot again... I tried this with my 'start' profile on and off and it didn't work. any other suggestions appreciated!

Comment: You can add an alert -> notify before and after the command to kill the app to check if that is what is making all that unwished things.